# Ubuntu 16.04; Not Sending Signal to Dual Monitor Setup But Works With Single Monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

so my problem is whenever I try plugging in a second monitor, Ubuntu just crashes. Everything works fine when only a single monitor is plugged in. When plugging in the second monitor and having Ubuntu stop sending a signal to the monitors, I've tried SSHing in to check /var/log/Xorg.0.log and see if the system can see either monitor at all, but no luck since the system crashes (still new to the OS; don't know if there are other logs I can check to help me out). Similar problem when I try booting up the system with both monitors plugged in: I make it to GRUB, and then Ubuntu crashes.

I've read through older forum questions and dug around Google for solutions. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Nvidia drivers and tried the Nouveau drivers found in Additional drivers (I have a GTX 970). Those solutions, and trying different wires (which shouldn't be the problem because this setup works with Windows), are about all I could find.

Any suggestions? If this is a duplicate question, then I definitely missed the first time this question was asked. If you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

**EDIT/UPDATE**

After running two scripts in the background and sending/updating the output from `xrandr` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep Monitor` to two separate files, after the system crashes, `xrandr` did show the second monitor and shows the status as 'connected' on the video card's port, but the second monitor never shows up in Xorg.0.log; only the primary one. Not sure how useful this information is, but thought I should include it here.

Comment: I have got the same issue at my end on my 16.04 machine and not able to fixed it. So Then I tried the same with another 16.04 machine and it worked without any issue.

Comment: Yea, I suspect that I'll just have to wipe and start from scratch to see if that helps. Its been a few months now and no solution.

Comment: I think it depends on which display configuration you are using. One of our machine which has 2 mini display port and it is connected to 2 HDMI monitor and it is working fine or I can say that it is the best combination which we are using and working in Ubuntu 16.04.